# Where is the mistake in my reasoning?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

I have a statement that says:

> If $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 2$ and $(a + b + c)(1 + ab + bc + ac) = 3^2$
>
> What is the value of $( a + b + c )$ ?

My reasoning was:

$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 2$, rewritten as:

1. $(a + b + c)^2 = 2 + 2ab + 2ac + 2bc$

Since,  $(a + b + c)(1 + ab + bc + ac) = 3^2$

2. $(1 + ab + bc + ac) = \frac{9}{(a + b + c)}$

Now, replacing in the 1.

3. Factorize $(a + b + c)^2 = 2(1 + ab + ac + bc)$
4. Replacing $(a + b + c)^2 = \frac{18}{a + b + c}$
5. Multiplying by $(a + b + c)$
6. $(a + b + c)^3 = 18$. Thus $a + b + c = \sqrt[3]{18}$. That is my result.

But, the correct result should be $4$, then where is my mistake ?

Comment: Well, I find the same as you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your work is perfectly correct. But I'm pretty sure you misinterpreted the original question: there should be $\color{green}{32}$, not $\color{red}{3^2}$, in the given data. With that value, the same work as you did will indeed yield $4$ as the final answer.

Comment: Good sleuthing.  This is a rare case where a screenshot or image of the original question might have been useful!

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: Note that if you type "32" into the Math SE Question or Answer box, it comes out with "3" sticking its tail below the line, but with "2" sitting on the line... I very much dislike this typographical inconsistency in many fonts...

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $a^2+b^2+c^2=2$ and $(a+b+c)(1+ab+bc+ac)=k$. Then, setting $s=a+b+c$ and $q=ab+bc+ac$, we get
$$
s^2=2+2q=2(1+q),\qquad s(1+q)=k
$$
Therefore $1+q=s^2/2$ and
$$
s^3=2k
$$
so that $s=\sqrt[3]{2k}$. If $s$ has to be $4$, then $2k=64$, that is, $k=32$.